# Type mismatch in for comprehension: getting "Product with Serializable"

Tags: scala, types, yield, for-comprehension

I'm writing a function that would take a list of character occurrences (`List[(Char, Int)]`) in a string, and produce all subsets of that occurrence list.

So, given

```
List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
```

It will produce

```
List(
  List(),
  List(('a', 1)),
  List(('a', 2)),
  List(('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
  List(('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
  List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
)
```

I've implemented it like this:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
  if (occurrences.isEmpty) List(List())
  else for {
    (c, n) <- occurrences
    i <- n to 1 by -1
  } yield (c, i) :: combinations(occurrences.tail)
```

And I get this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : List[List[Product with Serializable]]
 required: List[Occurrences]
    (which expands to)  List[List[(Char, Int)]]
```

Please help me understand, why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

I've tried re-writing it as a flatMap..., using Intellij's "Explain Scala code" etc.

Comment: Any particular reason that stops you from accepting the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Actually brackets are missing:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]

  def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
    if (occurrences.isEmpty) List(List())
    else (for {
      (c, n) <- occurrences
      i <- n to 1 by -1
    } yield (c, i)) :: combinations(occurrences.tail)
```

In you original code for comprehension tried to yield `(c, i) :: combinations(occurrences.tail)` which is `List` with `Any` element inside (`Tuple`/another `List`).

**UPDATE:**

The proper method that does required magic:

```
type Occurrences = List[(Char, Int)]


  /**
    * Returns the list of all subsets of the occurrence list.
    *  This includes the occurrence itself, i.e. `List(('k', 1), ('o', 1))`
    *  is a subset of `List(('k', 1), ('o', 1))`.
    *  It also include the empty subset `List()`.
    *
    *  Example: the subsets of the occurrence list `List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))` are:
    *
    *    List(
    *      List(),
    *      List(('a', 1)),
    *      List(('a', 2)),
    *      List(('b', 1)),
    *      List(('a', 1), ('b', 1)),
    *      List(('a', 2), ('b', 1)),
    *      List(('b', 2)),
    *      List(('a', 1), ('b', 2)),
    *      List(('a', 2), ('b', 2))
    *    )
    *
    *  Note that the order of the occurrence list subsets does not matter -- the subsets
    *  in the example above could have been displayed in some other order.
    */
  def combinations(occurrences: Occurrences): List[Occurrences] =
    occurrences.foldRight(List[Occurrences](Nil)) {
      case ((ltr, cnt), acc) =>
        acc ::: (for {
          comb <- acc
          ltrNum <- 1 to cnt
        } yield (ltr, ltrNum) :: comb)
    }
```

All kudos to the author of [this code](https://mwclearning.com/sourcecode/scala/forcomp/src/main/scala/forcomp/Anagrams.scala).

Comment: Parentheses solve the type, but change the intended behavior of the code. I'm trying to yield exactly `(c, i) :: combinations(occurrences.tail)`

Comment: Let's break it down: `combinations(occurrences.tail)` has type `List[List[(Char, Int)]]`. You try to append `(c, i)` which is `(Char, Int)`. You should append `List[(Char, Int)]`

Comment: However even after that it does not yield required result which makes me think that algorithm itself is not quite correct. I do not intend to post solution to the algorithmic problem as your question asks for compilation problem solving.

Comment: Please see the update, it contains method that does what you need.